# Tensorflow convert string column into multiple columns for classification

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have csv file in the following format

```
feature_1 | feature_2 | ... | feature_n | label
```

where the label is of type string. I have successfully read the file with `pandas` with:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("dataset/iris.csv", delimiter=",")
proced_data = data.values
```

However, as shown in the tensorflow MNIST example, the labels are formatted as

```
label_0 | label_1 | ... | label_9
```

where for one sample, only one of the labels is `1`, and all the others are `0`. As the label of my `proced_data` is one column of string, I am wondering what is the fastest way to convert it to the mnist-like format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has an one-hot encoder, so you could just use [`pd.get_dummies(..)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) to convert the labels to dummy variables.

In your case,

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("dataset/iris.csv", delimiter=",")
y = pd.get_dummies(data['label'])
```

Btw, one more note. You should do `import pandas as pd` and then do `pd.read_csv(..)`. This is a common approach for importing pandas as a package.